# WPF TwoWay Binding to a static class Property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, binding

There's no problem if Mode=OneWay, but I have this:
Class:

```
namespace Halt
{
    public class ProjectData
    {
            public static string Username {get;set;}
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
xmlns:engine="clr-namespace:Halt.Engine"
<TextBox Name="UsernameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,5,10,0" Height="25"
         Text="{Binding Source={x:Static engine:ProjectData.Username}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

This dont wanna work because of TwoWay mode. So how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the binding needs to be two-way, you must supply a path. There's a trick to do two-way binding on a static property, provided the class is not static : declare a dummy instance of the class in the resources, and use it as the source of the binding.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ProjectData x:Key="projectData"/>
</Window.Resources>
...

<TextBox Name="UsernameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,5,10,0" Height="25"
         Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource projectData}, Path=Username}"/>
```

Comment: Simple and easy. Cleaner than ViewModel btw. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not as simple and easy as could be in WPF 4.5.

Comment: @user1034912 *There's a trick to do two-way binding on a static property, provided the class is not static*

Answer (score 17):

Use the static property binding syntax (which is, as far as I know, available since WPF 4.5):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=(engine:ProjectData.Username)}"/>
```

No need to set `Mode="TwoWay"`, as that is the default for the `TextBox.Text` property anyway.

---

Although not explicitly asked for, you may also want to implement property change notification.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34763286/1136211) for how to do it.

Comment: Without Mode=OneWay error occured: "Error 1 Two-way binding requires Path or XPath."

Comment: Then you haven't used the above XAML. Read carefully, and write the binding Path exactly as shown here. Make sure that you use parentheses instead of curly braces. Do not set `Mode` at all, especially do not set `Mode="OneWay"`, because that is not what you want. I was just telling you that the binding to the Text property of a TextBox is two-way by default, so there is no need to set the Mode.

Comment: Hi all. Followup question: If, instead of textbox and string we're talking about a listbox and an array of strings, how can be this done ?

Comment: @zazkapulsk As usual, you would use a property of type  `ObservableCollection<string>` instead of an array.

Comment: @Clemens - would you please elaborate ?

Comment: @zazkapulsk Bind the ItemsSource property of a ListBox to a static property of type ObservableCollection<string>. That's it. If you have difficulties with it, ask another question on StackOverflow. Do not ask "follow-up" questions in comments. Before you ask, do not forget to put some effort in searching the web for already existing answers.

Comment: @Peter The question was about a problem with updating the source property. OP didn't seem to have the need for a change notification to update the target. However, I've added a link to another answer for an explanation how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

When I have to bind to a static property I use a ViewModel that has a property that gets and sets on the static property, for example

```
public class ProjectData
{
        public static string Username {get;set;}
}

public class ViewModel {
   public string UserName {
      get{ return ProjectData.Username ; }
      set { ProjectData.Username  = value; }
   }
}
```

Then I set an instance of ViewModel as the UI DataContext.