# Static binding doesn't update when resource changes

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd first like to say I'm very new to Binding.. I've done some things in WPF already but I never used binding because concept is a bit too hard to understand for me right of the bat. Even this what I'm doing now is something i managed to salvage from a tutorial that I didn't fully understand.

In my application I have a static class with static properties and there's a static method that changes those static properties.

Example:

```
public static class AppStyle
{
    public static SolidColorBrush property = Brushes.Red;


    public static void ChangeTheme()
    {
        property = Brushes.Blue;
    }
}
```

Inside the XAML I have a control that has it's background binded to this value. I even declared the namespace properly.

```
...
    xmlns:style="clr-namespace:CorrectNamespace;assembly=RightAssembly"
...
<TextBox x:Name="TXT_PN" 
     Background="{Binding Source={x:Static style:AppStyle.property}}"          
     TextChanged="TXT_PN_TextChanged" 
     Text="Text"/>
```

When the application loads it will load the correct setting (Red color) however when things change and ChangeTheme() is called, the static class will get the new value, however the textbox's Background will not change.
What am I doing wrong here? As I said, I'm very new to this and I would appreciate the solution in laymen's terms.

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, your `property` is actually not a property, but a field. A minimal property declaration would look like this:

```
public static SolidColorBrush Property { get; set; }
```

Please note the name is starting with an uppercase letter, which is a widely accepted coding convention in C#.

Because you also want to have a change notification fired whenever the value of the property changes, you need to declare a property-changed event (which for non-static properties is usually done by implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface).

For static properties there is a new mechanism in WPF 4.5 (or 4.0?), where you can write a static property changed event and property declaration like this:

```
public static class AppStyle
{
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

    private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private static SolidColorBrush property = Brushes.Red; // backing field

    public static SolidColorBrush Property
    {
        get { return property; }
        set
        {
            property = value;
            OnStaticPropertyChanged("Property");
        }
    }

    public static void ChangeTheme()
    {
        Property = Brushes.Blue;
    }
}
```

The binding to a static property would be written with the property path in parentheses:

```
Background="{Binding Path=(style:AppStyle.Property)}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth reply. Let me just add that I do use {get;set;} for my properties,I just missed it out here in my question. I have 1 more question regarding your answer; my class is in a dll which is in another project, do I write the first code block there or in .cs of the xaml I'm working in?

Comment: Thank you very much. I've applied your code and everything is now working. I'll make sure to remember this. Again, thank you! :)

Comment: I have 1 more question. Now that I'm using my bindings inside visual design view my background is transparent and it makes it a bit hard to order elements properly with no visible borders. Is there a way this can be mitigated?

Comment: Not sure. My expectation would be that the binding also works in design view. That's probably worth another StackOverflow question. However, you may probably set the Binding's FallbackValue.

Comment: if I do that, application loads with that value instead of the value defined in the class field as a fallback value which is not a good solution for practical reasons. I'll write another question when I get home. maybe there is a solution. thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks very much for this Q&A. I just want to note that the parentheses in `Path=(style:AppStyle.Property)` at the end are important to getting this to work. My code would compile without them but not update. It appeared the handler was never initialized.

Comment: @RossLlewallyn Sure they are. See [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.110).aspx) for all the details. Especially section *PropertyPath for Objects in Data Binding* -> *Single Property, Attached or Otherwise Type-Qualified*.

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me, why is my handler all ways null?

Answer (score 0):

To implement reaction on a change, you need to notify about the change. See INotifyPropertyChanged interface. However, you can't use it with a static class. What about a singleton (ideally using some dependency injection container) instead of a static class?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, Clemens' answer helped me a bit more. I stated that I'm new to binding and I have to say that I've never heard about some of the words you've mentioned. I know about the interface but I have no clue how to utilize it since I didn't get that far into C# yet