# Update textblock to value of variable in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

Edit: I want to update the value of a textblock to the value of a random variable that is generated periodically on another class.

My implementation is blocking other features in the app (buttons). Any suggestion?

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    TaskViewModel viewModel = new TaskViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
        Server_V2.AsyncService.runMain();
        DisplayAV();
    }

    //Display Availability
    private async void DisplayAV() {
        while (true) {
            //availabilityField.Text = Server_V2.AV.ToString();
            viewModel.Availability = Server_V2.AV.ToString();
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }

    public class TaskViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string availabilty = "0";
        public string Availability
        {
            get { return availabilty; }
            set { availabilty = value; OnStaticPropertyChanged();}
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should add what you have tried (code) to the answer. Even it is not running. Without showing effort, you will get no help from the community.

Comment: Can I see what you have tried? What other implementations are you referring too? Could you show me the class and how you you access the variables? Are you using events since it's periodically going to be updated? A timer maybe?

Comment: In case `AV` is meant to be a static property in class Server_V2, follow the instructions given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34763286/1136211

Comment: Please just add the code you got confused with.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you. That helped a lot. I'm still running into a problem, as the textblock is blocking other operation in the app. (See code above)

Comment: @Ben @ Bjørn Code added.

Comment: Better update the Availability property in a Tick event handler of a DispatcherTimer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a background worker.  You async code still runs on the main thread.

Like this...

```
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
        Server_V2.AsyncService.runMain();
        worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //availabilityField.Text = Server_V2.AV.ToString();
            viewModel.Availability = Server_V2.AV.ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I understand I should use background workers for all my interactions with the UI elements, but what's the main difference processing-wise between a background worker and task?

Comment: From this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index:  "The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread."  Async/await is a way of composing code.  Your problem requires another thread which is what background worker does.