# C# WPF ListView not deleting items properly

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, delete-row, selecteditem

I have a `ListView` which looks like this;

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Viewer.URLLinks"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Viewer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="URLLinks" Height="461.215" Width="606.542" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="proxyListView" Loaded="proxyListView_Loaded">
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="contextMenu1">
                <MenuItem Name="item1" Header="Delete" Click="item1_Click"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I am trying to add a `ContextMenu` to delete `SelectedItem`
This is the code behind;

```
public partial class URLLinks : Window
{
    public URLLinks()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void proxyListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        proxyListView.ItemsSource = GlobalVars.URLLinks;
    }

    private void item1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalVars.URLLinks.RemoveAt(proxyListView.SelectedIndex);
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(proxyListView.ItemsSource);
        //view.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** this is the variable and how it is set

```
public static async void GetLink(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            string sURL = url;
            Uri uri = new Uri(sURL);
            string host = uri.Host;
            using (HttpClient clientduplicate = new HttpClient())
            {
                clientduplicate.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident / 6.0)");
                using (HttpResponseMessage responseduplicate = await clientduplicate.GetAsync(sURL))
                {
                    using (HttpContent contentduplicate = responseduplicate.Content)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string resultduplicate = await contentduplicate.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            var websiteduplicate = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                            websiteduplicate.LoadHtml(resultduplicate);
                            List<string> ListItems = new List<string>();
                            Settings.Default.Reload();
                            int maxLinks = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Settings.Default["subLinksValue"]) * 10));

                            foreach (HtmlNode links in websiteduplicate.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                            {
                                HtmlAttribute att = links.Attributes["href"];
                                foreach (var link in att.Value.Split(' '))
                                {
                                    if (ListItems.Count >= maxLinks)
                                    {
                                        GlobalVars.URLLinks = ListItems;
                                        //File.WriteAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\links.txt", ListItems.ToArray());
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    if (link.StartsWith("http") && link.Contains(host) && CheckURLValid(link))
                                    {
                                        ListItems.Add(link);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            GlobalVars.URLLinks = ListItems;
                            //File.WriteAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\links.txt", ListItems.ToArray());
                            //return ListItems;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error getting links");
                            //return null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error, url not formatted correctly. Try coping your url from your browser");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use  an ObservableCollection for `URLLinks`. There is no need for `view.Refresh();`

Comment: Change it to `public static IList<string> URLLinks = new ObservableCollection<string>();`

Comment: It won't update. I am on Window 7 btw.
P.S. You mean add INotifyCollectionChanged?

Comment: No, just ObservableCollection instead of List.

Comment: Won't do the trick

Comment: Then there's something you haven't shown us, sorry.

Comment: I literally copy pasted the code in here in case you have any doubts.
I don't think there is something i am hiding

Comment: @Clemens i think you were write. It should be the function updating GlobalVars.URLLinks.
Updated code above

Comment: Do not reassign URLLinks. Create and assign an ObservableCollection once, then only call Clear, Add and Remove. Besides that, you shouldn't declare `async void` methods (except for event handlers). Declare `async Task` instead and await the method call.

Comment: And `Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Settings.Default["subLinksValue"]) * 10));` is just horrible. Use the generated Setting member (Settings.Default.SubLinksValue ?) instead.

Comment: Why not reassign it? What it has to do with the fact that it doesn't work properly, the items are not removed from the list?

Comment: If you reassign it, it must fire a property change notification, e.g. the [StaticPropertyChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34763286/1136211).

Comment: @Clemens you are right, didn't think of it. That sloved it. Post it as an answer, you deserve it.
And sorry for my messy post ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I had to do in order to get this to work is change your collection from `List<string>` to `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Once you do that, you don't need to reset the items on the list view.

```
static ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Item 1", "Item 2" };

private void proxyListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    proxyListView.ItemsSource = items;
}

private void item1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    items.RemoveAt(proxyListView.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Does the fact that my items list is on another class affect this. Because when I move my list within the same form it works, when it is on Glabal scope, it doesn't?

Comment: @JohnP. Negative. I moved the ```items``` property to another class and it worked just fine.

Comment: @JohnP. What behavior are you getting with my solution?

Comment: It should be the function updating GlobalVars.URLLinks.
Updated main thread

Answer (score 2):

Even if you're not going to go the full MVVM route, at least use an ObservableCollection of items and assign your ListView's ItemSource to that. This will automatically update the control when an item is removed or added.

Trying to perform business logic operations on a U.I. control will soon degenerate into a big ball of spaghetti.

Answer (score 2):

If `GlobalVars.URLLinks` returns an `ObservableCollection<T>` or any other custom type that implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, this will work:

```
private void item1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ic = proxyListView.ItemsSource as IList<string>;
    ic.RemoveAt(proxyListView.SelectedIndex);
}
```

But if the source collection doesn't raise change notifications when items are removed (a `List<T>` doesn't), you will have to re-set the `ItemsSource` property after you have removed an item to refresh the `ListView`:

```
private void item1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GlobalVars.URLLinks.RemoveAt(proxyListView.SelectedIndex);
    proxyListView.ItemsSource = GlobalVars.URLLinks;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer with the variable public static List<string> URLLinks = new List<string>();

Comment: @JohnP. So you need to change the type of the source collection to `ObservableCollection<T>` or re-set the `ItemsSource`. See my answer and edit.

Comment: That is why i am saying it doesnt work properly.
The second solution you suggest is the one i was using.
It doesn't always remove the selected item.

Comment: It's not the one you have used in the sample code you have posted. How many items are there in the list and what does `proxyListView.SelectedIndex` return then?

Comment: The second solution doesn't work, try it for your-self. SelectedIndex returns the index. The items inside are random. Can be 5, can be 500

Comment: @mm8 I'm getting ```Index out of range``` exceptions for both of these solutions after the first one gets removed, fyi.

Comment: @James Sure, since selection is gone after you've deleted the selected item. SelectedIndex will go to -1 then. Of course you have to check if the index is valid. But that is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @JohnP: Of course the SelectedIndex  returns the selected index... what item are you trying to remove? Maybe you want to use Remove instread of RemoveAt?