# Possible to use constant/static value inside a binding in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, constants

We are using the following mechanism/syntax to bind commands in XAML:

```
Command="{Binding CommandAggregator[FooCmd], Mode=OneTime}"
```

Here, `CommandAggregator` is an object that you can use an indexer (with `string` parameter) on to get back the actual command.

The command registrations with the aggregator are bugging me a bit, because we are still using magic strings for the command names like this:

```
this.CommandAggregator.SetCommand("FooCmd", new RelayCommand(execute, canExecute));
```

While I don't necessarily like this whole process, I cannot change much. The one thing I would like to do for now is quit using magic strings by making them constants or `static readonly string` objects inside a static `CommandName` class.

But **is it possible to define the binding inside the XAML and reference the constant** (say `CommandName.Foo`)? I thought about using `{x:Static ...}`, but I don't know how to get the returned value into the indexer.

Comment: You can bind to static properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31611110/1136211

Comment: @Clemens This looks promising, but I cannot get `Binding CommandAggregator[(common:CommandName.Foo)]` to work; no binding error in the output either. I will now try to supply the whole path. Code completion does offer me the `common:CommandName` part, but none of its properties or constants.

Comment: You can't use anything else than a literal (string or integer) key in a binding property path. Declare static properties in your CommandAggregator class and bind `Binding (local:CommandAggregator.FooCmd)`

Comment: @Clemens Ah, so that's why! I will have to check if I may even do that (as it's an external component). Maybe I'm out of luck here. Thanks a lot for the suggestion though, I definitely learned something new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement an `IValueConverter` which will return a command from CommandAggregator based on converter Parameter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var aggregator = value as CommandAggregator;
    var cmd = parameter as string;
    if (aggregator != null && cmd != null)
       return aggregator[cmd];
    return null;
}
```

and pass the parameter from xaml:

```
Command="{Binding Path=CommandAggregator,
                  Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, 
                  ConverterParameter={x:Static Constants.FooCmd},
                  Mode=OneTime}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this and it works perfectly. It's a little more verbose, but I think still beneficial. That code is also very unlikely to change but likely to be copy/pasted for new command registrations. Btw, you forgot to add the `Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}` part to the command binding.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best, but it works for me. I didn't like so many CmdWhatEvers for my Relay commands showing up in my debugger so moved them to a dictionary, which seems similar to your CommandAggregator, then indexed them with a static string (magic strings have caused so many binding failures for me.)
Anyway, my string constants live in a static class

```
internal static class Str
{
    public static readonly string CmdReset = "CmdReset";
}
```

In the View Model

```
internal class CtrlVm : ViewModelBase
{
    public Dictionary<string, IRelayCommand> Commands { get; }

    public CtrlVm()
    {
        Commands = new Dictionary<string, IRelayCommand>()
        {
            // My relay command class takes, Execute, CanExecute
            //  and a Header parameter, that I use in binding
            Str.CmdReset, new RelayCommand(Reset, CanReset, "Reset");
        },
    }
    private bool CanReset(object parameter)
    {
        return bHasChanges; // or whatever
    }
    private void Reset(object parameter)
    {
        // do the reset work
    }
}
```

Then in the Xaml

`<Button Command= "{Binding Commands[CmdReset]}"
        Content= "{Binding Commands[CmdReset].Header}"/>`